# AND operator inside While statement in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm working on a homework assignment and have run into a problem with using an AND operator inside my while loop's statement. Here's a simplified example of the problem:

```
int main()
{
int a = 4;
int b = 0;
int c;

while (a <= 10 && b <= 10) {
    cout << "a " << a << endl;
    cout << "b " << b << endl << endl;
    ++a;
    ++b;
    }
cout << "done" << endl;

return 0 ;
}
```

So I want the while loop to run as long as BOTH a and b are less than or equal to 10. However, the while loops is ended as soon as a goes above 10, as shown here:
[image]

Comment: _So I want the while loop to run as long as BOTH a and b are less than or equal to 10_. So why are you complaining when `a` goes above 10?

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is above 10, then it's redundant to check `b` since `false && anything` is `false`. But this is what you want:

> So I want the while loop to run as long as BOTH a and b are less than
>   or equal to 10

If you want to enter the loop if *any* of the variables is less than or equal to 10, use `||` instead.

Read more about [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to better understand this.

Comment: Sigh. Don't know how I kept looking over that. I must be retarded. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop executed exactly what you want:

> while loop to run as long as BOTH a and b are less than or equal to 10

The while loop exit when the first condition (a<=10) is false.
You may want to reconsider the logic of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your while condition

```
while (a <= 10 && b <= 10)
```

to

```
while (a <= 10 || b <= 10)
```

As `OR` condition is false only both the testing condition are false..